# Google Sheets authentication expires every few hours or so

Tags: flask, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm currently using [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) to access a Google Sheets document continuously on a web server.

It’s hosted on a Flask web server (apache WSGI), so the connection to Google has to be continuous and continuously authenticated.

I’m having an issue where after a few hours, I’ll need to regenerate the book object (re-authenticate) or I’ll get this issue (see below).

Below is what I’ve done to try to solve the issue, but I’m still getting the same issue and was wondering if you had any ideas.

There are 5-6 different sheets, and I’m creating a Class with different methods for accessing each sheet (all inheriting from Access).

```
book = authorise()
employee, shift, clock, client, payment = Employee(book), Shift(book), 
Clock(book), Client(book), Payment(book)

def refresh_google_access(self): #CALLED EVERY 40 MINUTES
   book = authorise()
   employee._refresh(book)
   shift._refresh(book)
   clock._refresh(book)
   client._refresh(book)
   payment._refresh(book)

def authorise():
   scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
   credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('clocker/access.json', scope)
   gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
   book = gc.open_by_key(SHEET_KEY)

   return book

class Access:
   def _refresh(self, book):
       self.__init__(book)

class Employee(Access):

   def __init__(self, book):
       self.sheet = book.worksheet("Employee List")

   ...

class Clock(Access):

   def __init__(self, book):
       self.sheet = book.worksheet("Time Log")

   ...

class Shift(Access):

   def __init__(self, book):
       self.sheet = book.worksheet("Shift List")
   ...

class Client(Access):

   def __init__(self, book):
       self.sheet = book.worksheet("Client List")

   ...

class Payment(Access):

   def __init__(self, book):
       self.sheet = book.worksheet("Payments")

   ...
```

After a few hours (anywhere between 4-24 hours), I'll get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/ve/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
   File "/home/ve/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
   File "/home/ve/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
   File "/home/ve/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
     raise value
   File "/home/ve/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.dispatch_request()
   File "/home/ve/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
   File "/var/www/clocker/clocker/routes.py", line 43, in voice
     clocked_in = clock.is_clocked_in(id)
   File "/var/www/clocker/clocker/sheet_access.py", line 115, in is_clocked_in
     latest_clock_in = self.get_latest_clock_in(id)
   File "/var/www/clocker/clocker/sheet_access.py", line 107, in get_latest_clock_in
     result = self.sheet.findall(str(id))
   File "/home/ve/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 814, in findall
     return list(self._finder(filter, query))
   File "/home/ve/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 779, in _finder
     data = self.spreadsheet.values_get(self.title)
   File "/home/ve/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 110, in values_get
     r = self.client.request('get', url, params=params)
   File "/home/ve/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 79, in request
     raise APIError(response)
 gspread.exceptions.APIError: {
   "error": {
     "code": 401,
     "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
     "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
   }
 }
```

This can be fixed nearly every time by just restarting the server.

Regenerating the book object doesn't seem to fix the issue, I've checked that the `id` of the book changes every 40 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, in my usage I would hold onto `gc` and call `book = gc.open_by_key(SHEET_KEY)` when you need the data.

Basically instead of saving `book` as a global variable, save `gc` so that your previously authenticated session is retained and used for further requests.